# How to make a big string(aka str picture) print one after another?

Tags: python, string

```
+___ +___ +___ 
|1 / |2 / |3 / 
|__\ |__\ |__\ 
|    |    |
```

I am trying to make flags appear one after another and the only way I can think of is to assign every part of the picture to various variables(that means to add `top = '+___'` and so on).But if it does work with smaller pictures,what should I do with bigger ones?Creating an array and iterating through it s also not a good solution in plan of time and memory.
I tried to attach everything in one string,but using `end=''` it doesn't shape the form the way I need(only from the new line).
I will appreciate your advices,thanks in advance.

```
n = int(input())
flag = """
+___  
|  /  
|__\  
|   
"""
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print(flag[:9] + str(i) + flag[10:])
```

P.S.-It's an exercise I found,but have no idea how to solve efficiently.

Comment: For any printable ascii art pictures i wouldn't be concerned with the size of the needed lists and the associated iterations. Pick you battles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print just side by side - your cursor moves to the next line, every print will

> top = '+___'

You can split your picture into separate lines. It makes a list you can iterate.

Then you can print the multiple of some string using simple multiplication `*`:

```
n = int(input())
flag = """
+___  
|  /  
|__\  
|     
"""
for line in flag.split("\n"):
    print(line * n)
```

Result:

```
+___  +___  +___  +___  +___  
|  /  |  /  |  /  |  /  |  /  
|__\  |__\  |__\  |__\  |__\  
|     |     |     |     |
```

But this only works if your original flag had all lines equal length. If you don't want to make sure you have spaces in there, you can add padding later. Either using string formatting or some clever tricks.

As for the number, string formatting is your friend!

```
flag = """
+___  
|{} /  
|__\  
|     
"""
```

Notice how the flag is broken a bit here - `{}` are two characters but we'll use only one digit in its place!

Then we need an inner loop because each flag needs a different number.

```
for line in flag.split("\n"):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(line.format(i), end="") #by default each print is one line, we want to stay in the same line!
    print() #print the new line only after n * part of the flag is printed
```

Result:

```
+___  +___  +___  +___  +___  
|1 /  |2 /  |3 /  |4 /  |5 /  
|__\  |__\  |__\  |__\  |__\  
|     |     |     |     |
```

Comment: You'll gain some experience too. ;) Just have an interpreter open and test parts of code or whether your trick or formatting works. And familiarize yourself with documentation - e.g. things like string formatting are pretty powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see why iterating would be a problem actually, except indeed if you print millions of flags. And for time I think it will be the fastest. Anyway, **optimization is always the last thing you want to do**, you need a working algorithm first.

I will not actually solve the exercise, but are a few things.
You can go line by line first and use the mighty star operator:

```py
print("ORA  " * n)
print("MUDA " * n)
```

As all characters have the same spacing, you can see it prints fine. It is important to check that all lines have the same number of characters though, or to pad it (insert whitespaces in the end of the line for instance).

Now, concerning changing a letter, you need to change a bit your algorithm:

```py
print("ORA   " * n)
for i in range(n):
    print("HELLO ".replace('E', i))
print(i)
print("MUDA  " * n)
```

If you are concerned that your teacher will not like this coding style, first, that is sweet of you, and then you can indeed use an array, a bit like this:

```py
# Notice that all my line have the same length
flag = """
ORA  
MUDA 
"""

f_lines = flag.split("\n")
for l in f_lines:
    print(l * n)
```

With that in mind, I think you have all the keys you need to solve your exercise.

Comment: Yeah,thanks for advice about the algorithms.Still a little bit inexpirienced(only 3 month of programming) and forget about it sometimes.

Comment: Oh, you are just starting. Welcome to you then! And yeah, optimization is nice and challenging but it is better to have a working algorithm.